# Is it possible to get ProbBank verb sense for a given sentence using NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

I want to get the role set of a verb using PropBank. NLTK has a method to get the PropBank role set if we give the exact verb sense to it as follows.

```
from nltk.corpus import propbank
expose_01 = propbank.roleset('expose.01')
```

For a given sentence, is there a way to identify this verb sense (ex: expose.01)?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for? Do you mean you need some way for "prop sense disambiguation"? Or do you mean how to get all prop sense of the word "expose"? There's no way to get a prop sense given a single word without context. And with context, there's no way to get the correct prop sense without some smart algorithm or manual labelling.

Comment: Thank you. What I wanted to know whether there is a verb sense disambiguation function implemented in NLTK for propbank like its wsd.

Comment: No there isn't. But you can get the verb frame within the propbank for instances inside the annotated penn tree bank.